# The loop what loop? Recursion?

Tags: javascript, loops

Just learning javascript with three.js and got confused with the loop I'm used to this approach:

```js
var stuff = 1;
var runLoop = true;
while(runLoop)
  {
    stuff += 1;
    if (stuff == 10000)
      {
        runLoop = false;
      }
  }
```

but with three.js examples

```js
var render;
render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube3.rotation.x += 0.0001;
    cube.rotation.x += 0.001;
    cube2.rotation.x += 0.001;

    cube3.rotation.y += 0.0005;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.001;
    cube2.rotation.y += 0.001;

    cube3.rotation.z += 0.0001;
    cube.rotation.z += 0.001;
    cube2.rotation.z += 0.001;

    cube4.rotation.z += 0.001;



    cube.geometry.vertices[0] = {x: countX, y: 0.5, z: 0.5};

    countX += 0.00001;
    cube.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

I don't know why this is looping in this function. Is renderer.render(scene, camera) calling the function render() again? or this there more to this I don't understand?

Comment: `I don't know why this is looping in this function`, doesn't immediately make sense, because you have some loop at the top and the question is related to render function that doesn't seem to use that loop.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(render);` <-- pass the render function (yes, that's a function you're passing as an argument) to `requestAnimationFrame`. It then schedules the function you pass to it (in this case, `render`) to be called at some future time (in this case, the next time the browser processes animations). So it's `requestAnimationFrame` that's doing it, not `renderer.render`

Comment: I had some encouragement for you on a question you deleted *Where Can I Find Good Simple Clean JavaScript Projects?*:  The pong game would give you a good overview of using canvas for  drawing, animating, user input. I would suggest you find some basic canvas-pong "on-the-nets". First try to understand it. Then try to improve it. When you feel it's solid code, take it to our sister site and ask the pro's to review your code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  Good luck -- it's inspiring to have you wanting to create excellent code instead of knock-it-out code!

Comment: @markE Thanks for your encouragement! Maybe I worded the question wrong like many other questions? I am aware of github, sourceforge, bitbucket etc. I am a fan of Douglas Crockford and believe style and maintainability is more important then speed. I can throw things together all right but was looking for GREAT examples I can use as references. I can look at code and it makes sense to me but is it to Crockford's standards? Example theoretical pong game: 300 lines of canvas and logic looks great, but now I want to make it 4 player then add web-sockets becomes troublesome.Great style references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render function is being supplied to the requestAnimationFrame function thus creating a loop. You're right, recursion is occurring, something like this:

```
function requestAnimationFrame(snapShotFunction) {
    // Do some math to wait a certain amount of time before
    // computing the next snapshot based various factors

    // Show current snapshot
    snapShotFunction();
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    // more code
}
```

Comment: Technically it's not recursion but task scheduling. Think of `requestAnimationFrame` as a cronjob scheduler.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Just then don't  know why it's looping though all the "// more code" if requestAnimationFrame(render) is calling render() before. You would think requestAnimationFrame(render) would need to be at the bottom of the block to actually reach // more code

Comment: @abflett Since the requestAnimationFrame waits a certain amount of time, it can wait long enough after your computer has had time to process code in your render function.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the browser doesn't update the display until the call stack clears. If you run a `while (true)`, then the function you're in will always be on the stack without clear.  We can solve this by calling `requestAnimationFrame`, which lets the stack clear, but then runs your function after some milliseconds have passed.